# C# read file in DWORD blocks

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream, dword

I am trying to read a binary file into a byte array.

I need to read the file in blocks of DWORDs (or 4 bytes) and store each block into a single element of the byte array. This is what I have achieved so far.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var block = new byte[4];
    while (true)
    {
       byte[] temp = new byte[4];
       fs.Read(temp, 0, 4);
       uint read = (byte)BitConverter.ToUInt32(temp, 0);
       block[0] = read???
    }
}
```

However, converting the `uint read` to the element at `block[0]` is not working. I can't seem to find a way that doesn't produce errors.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You need a bit mask.

Comment: My question is: why are you converting `temp` to a `uint` if you need it in a `byte[]` form?

Comment: Your description is unclear to me.  A block is a DWORD, and you want each block to go into a single element of a byte array?That makes no sense. Please describe what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that even though each element of the file is a DWORD (4 byte little-endian unsigned integer), the value of each integer will never be more than 255, and therefore you are extracting the value as a byte?  If so, can you just use the value of `temp[0]` as your byte value and ignore the other three bytes?  Also a `BinaryReader` class may help you achieve this without reading the raw data and `BitConverter`ing it.

Comment: No amount of technical help can get your around logical impossibilities, such as wanting to fit a quart into a pint pot, or here where you apparently want to store 4 bytes into a single byte. If that's *not* what you're trying to do, please edit your narrative and make it far clearer what your overall task is here.

Comment: Sorry, I realise myself where I messed up. Of course, a byte variable can only store a uint value of 255. When I read the dword value I need to process it as a dword or uint, then write the processed value back to a file. How can that be done - with or without bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
// read all bytes from file
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("data.dat");

// create an array of dwords by using 4 bytes in the file
var dwords = Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length / 4)
                       .Select(index => BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, index * 4))
                       .ToArray();

// down-casting to bytes
var dwordsAsBytes = dwords.Select(dw => (byte)dw).ToArray();
```

Comment: You could also do `.Select(index => bytes[index * 4])`  As it's unsigned, that's effectively what you do by downcasting a uint32 to a byte.  However, your method will appropriately except if the value in the uint is larger than 255.

Comment: Is there a way to downcast from dword by splitting it into 4 separate bytes. e.g. `uint 0xABCDEF12 => byte[] {0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x12}`?

Comment: @Zeller33 Sure,just use [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1184xdy4(v=vs.110).aspx)